# Proving that roots of $P_n(z) := \sum k^3 z^k$ satisfy $|z| < 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

For each positive integer $n$, define the polynomial
$$
P_n(z) = z + 2^3z^2 + ... + n^3z^n.
$$ 
Prove that the roots of $P_n(z)$ lie inside the unit circle.

---

Assuming the existence of $|\alpha| \geq 1, P_n(\alpha) = 0$, I tried using the triangle inequality: 
$$
|\alpha|^nn^3 = |\alpha + 8\alpha^3 + ... + (n-1)^3 \alpha^{n-1} | \leq |\alpha| + ... + (n-1)^3 |\alpha|^{n-1}
$$
which seems to be too weak to create a contradiction.

Thoughts/solutions are appreciated.

Comment: have you tried rouche's theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) says that the roots of the derivative of a polynomial are in the convex hull of the roots of the polynomial.
So:

The roots of $f_n(z) = 1 + z + \ldots + z^n = (z^n-1)/(z-1)$ are roots of unity, and lie on the unit circle.
The roots of $f'_n(z) = \sum_{j=1}^n j z^{j-1}$ lie in the convex hull of these.
Since the roots of $f_n$ are all simple, they are not roots of $f'_n$, so the roots of $f'_n$ are (strictly) inside the unit circle.

The roots of $g_n(z) = z f'_n(z) = \sum_{j=1}^n j z^j$ are $0$ and the roots of $f'_n(z)$, so again these are strictly inside the unit circle.

Iterating this process, we find that for all positive integers $k$, the roots of
$\sum_{j=1}^n j^k z^j$ are strictly inside the unit circle.